# Scraping data from table

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract data from the table present on web page `http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/afenterprises/profit-lossVI/AFE01#AFE01`
I don't need the entire table at once but specific elements
X-path for 1st element is

```
/html/body/center[2]/div/div[1]/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]
```

i wrote a code

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)

FJ<-htmlParse("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/afenterprises/profit-lossVI/AFE01#AFE01")
data<-xpathSApply(FJ,"/html/body/center[2]/div/div[1]/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")
print(data)
```

the output comes out to be `NULL`

Comment: the function `htmlParse` is not in `rvest`, do you mean `XML`?

Comment: Yes sorry i was using both the libraries.
'XML' and 'rvest'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed a `div` in between and you did basically a wrong "*turn*"...

```
xpathSApply(FJ,"/html/body/center[2]/div/div[1]/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tr[6]/td[2]")
xmlValue(xpathSApply(FJ,"/html/body/center[2]/div/div[1]/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tr[6]/td[2]")[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail but it is returning '<td align="right" class="detb">53,983.00</td>'
How can i get the XML Value

Comment: you mean the 53,983.00

Comment: Yes how can i get This value '53,983.00'